# Why and how can K-means get trapped in local minimum?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I have studied K-means. I have understood this   algorithm    uses  a  residual  sum   of   squares   (RSS) where
$RSS_{K} = \sum_{p \in s}|{p-m(s)}|^2$,
$RSS = \sum_{k= 1}^{K}{RSS_{K}}$ is the  convergence  criterion. RSS is the objective function of $K$-means and our goal is to minimize it.

$m(s) = \frac{1}{|s|} \sum_{p \in s}{p}$
where $p$ is the datapoint belonging to cluster $s$.

***What does this mean:*  K-means get trapped in a local minimum in this context.** I am not getting the mathematical insight of it.

Comment: does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63857914/what-does-it-mean-for-the-k-means-algorithm-to-be-trapped-in-a-local-minimum

Comment: no it is not what i looking for

Answer (score 1):

After a lot research found this paper. It explains how Keans is trying to solve for local minimum not global minimum. Please read section 3.1 of this https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221620338_Convergence_Properties_of_the_K-Means_Algorithms

Comment: Thanks!. But my question is to know why K-means stuck/gives us bad result when there are too many local minima in the dataset

Comment: @Silverstalon You might need to edit your question, especially the title, as I didn't get that from reading your question.

Comment: @DarrenCook mine objective is as same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4419857/how-to-prove-that-the-residual-sum-of-squares-is-a-non-convex-function